# Google Maps API Street view displaying grey

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display the interior of businesses through the google maps api street view. I am first retrieving the places_id and using that to retrieve any street view panorama's that might be available. This was working earlier in the week and has stopped. I cannot figure out why, though. The div to show the interactive map displays grey with a few of the google artifacts and an error is logged to the console that the google generated url returned a 404.  Has anyone encountered this?

The code below is also in my **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sy1yhxvq/28/)**

```
var map;
var panorama;

$('#thebutton').click(function () {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var place_id = 'ChIJ-_RcvsBV2YARhkUbjSD3Vi4';
    var placeservice = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    var placesRequest = {
        placeId: place_id
    };

    placeservice.getDetails(placesRequest, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results.geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(results.name);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
            var brewerystreetview = new google.maps.LatLng(results.geometry.location.A, results.geometry.location.F);

            var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
            panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(results.geometry.location.lat(), results.geometry.location.lng()),
                zoom: 0
            });
            sv.getPanorama({
                location: brewerystreetview,
                radius: 0
            }, processSVData);
        }
    });
});

function processSVData(data, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: data.location.latLng,
            map: map,
            title: data.location.description
        });

        panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
        panorama.setPov({
            heading: 0,
            pitch: 0
        });
        panorama.setVisible(true);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

            var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
            // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID.
            panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
            panorama.setPov({
                heading: 0,
                pitch: 0
            });
            panorama.setVisible(true);
            panorama.show();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a side note as it doesn't seem to be the main issue: `var brewerystreetview = new google.maps.LatLng(results.geometry.location.A, results.geometry.location.F);` A & F are undocumented properties. You should use the `lat()` and `lng()` functions instead so `new google.maps.LatLng(results.geometry.location.lat(), results.geometry.location.lng());` (you do that a few lines below...)

Comment: Hey @MrUpsidown, thanks for the suggestion. I made that small change and the panorama started filling in as expected! **Except for on my android. Ugh** Not sure why this worked with the undocumented properties a day or two ago. But, I'll take it! Thanks!

Comment: Well, these properties are subject to change, especially if you don't force an API version. But there is something strange here cause I changed that in your fiddle like an hour ago and it didn't work. And now it works. The error was that `getPanorama` was not a function (?!). I even tried with an older API version and the problem was identical. So I'd think that Google was having an issue?

Comment: It is possible, but I usually doubt my code first, second and third before pointing at anything else. :) This issue happened for most of the day for me (whereas yesterday it worked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. FYI, the  .getPanorama function is new in v3.21 (v.exp), before that (v3.20 and earlier) it was .getPanoramaById and .getPanoramaByLocation. I suspect that the API changed underneath you (the experimental version, which you are served by default changed from v3.20 to v3.21)
2. You should *never* use undocumented properties of the Google Maps Javascript API (results.geometry.location.A, results.geometry.location.F), those can and do change with every release of the API. In most places you are using these, you can just used the returned `google.maps.LatLng` rather than creating a new one.
3. a StreetViewPanorama doesn't have a `center` option, should be `position`:

```
panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), {
    center: results.geometry.location,
    zoom: 0
});
```

should be:

```
panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), {
    position: results.geometry.location,
    zoom: 0
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sy1yhxvq/36/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var panorama;

$('#thebutton').click(function() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var place_id = 'ChIJ-_RcvsBV2YARhkUbjSD3Vi4';
  var placeservice = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var placesRequest = {
    placeId: place_id
  };
  placeservice.getDetails(placesRequest, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results.geometry.location
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(results.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
      var brewerystreetview = results.geometry.location;

      var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
      panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), {
        position: results.geometry.location,
        zoom: 0
      });
      sv.getPanorama({
        location: brewerystreetview,
        radius: 0
      }, processSVData);
    }
  });
});

function processSVData(data, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: data.location.latLng,
      map: map,
      title: data.location.description
    });

    panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
    panorama.setPov({
      heading: 0,
      pitch: 0
    });
    panorama.setVisible(true);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

      var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
      // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID.
      panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
      panorama.setPov({
        heading: 0,
        pitch: 0
      });
      panorama.setVisible(true);
      panorama.show();
    });
  }
}
```

```css
 div#pano {
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
   float: left;
 }
 div#map-canvas {
   width: 100%;
   height: 25%;
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div class="container" id="infocontainer" style=""><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="thebutton" onclick="return false;">Click here</a>
</div>
<div id="pano"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip! I tried to upvote your answer but my reputation is still too low. :(

Comment: Painfully it seems there was another change again recently,. even the updated fiddle gives a gray screen atm